# INSERT error using C#/Asp.Net/SQL

Tags: c#

I have tried to run the query to insert data into the database, but I got error while runnnig the code..

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available connection. The
>   connection's current state is closed.

Could you please tell me what the error is and why it happened?

```
{
    con2.Open();

    if (TextBox1.Text == "")
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('please enter Login Name')</script>");
    }
    else if (TextBox2.Text == "")
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('please enter Password')</script>");
    }
    else if (TextBox3.Text == "")
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('please enter Confirm Password')</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        //if (TextBox2.Text == TextBox3.Text)
        //{

            string a;
            a = "insert into tbl_Purchase_Users(Login_Name, Password, Uname, Uid, EmailID, Role, Status) values(@LName, @Pswd, @Uname, @uid, @Eid, @role, @stat)";
            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(a, con1);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", TextBox1.Text);

            string original;
            original = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
            int h = original.GetHashCode();
            string withHash = original;
            b1 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(withHash);
            encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(b1);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pswd", encrypted);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", TextBox3.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", TextBox4.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eid", TextBox5.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", TextBox6.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", TextBox7.Text);

            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("<Script>alert('inserted')</script>");
        }
        con2.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have opened con2 only not con1.
You passed con1 in SqlCommand.
Use the below code:

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(a, con2);
```

Comment: Thanks friend.. This is what the small mistakes i made.. thanks for correcting me

Comment: @user1402552 If an answer helped you,then you need to accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the connection called con2 but you are using con1 on you SqlCommand.

From what I can see you haven't opened con1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two different SqlConnection objects - con1 and con2. You are opening con2, but passing in con1 to the SqlCommand constructor.

As the error message states, the connection that you are using must be open.

If you pass con2 to the SqlCommand constructor, or if you open con1, your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the the `con1` is opend, since the only `.Open()` call shown in your call related to `con2`

```
con1.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

just use one connection object like

```
 con2.Open();
 SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(a, con2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see con1.open(). you have used Con1 in Sqlcommand. 
Please open
Con1.Open();

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connect with database by using Open(), in ur case con1.Open(); then perform action and close the connection. con1.Close();
else
    {
        //if (TextBox2.Text == TextBox3.Text)
        //{

```
        string a;
        a = "insert into tbl_Purchase_Users(Login_Name,Password,Uname,Uid,EmailID,Role,Status) values(@LName,@Pswd,@Uname,@uid,@Eid,@role,@stat)";
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(a, con1);
        con1.Open();
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", TextBox1.Text);

        string original;
        original = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
        int h = original.GetHashCode();
        string withHash = original;
        b1 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(withHash);
        encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(b1);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pswd", encrypted);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", TextBox3.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", TextBox4.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eid", TextBox5.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", TextBox6.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", TextBox7.Text);

        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("<Script>alert('inserted')</script>");
        con1.Close();
```

}